# Django: How to validate / Validator a "greater then" between two FormFields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am testing writing validator in django. So far it worked, but now i would like to write something like a "range".

> forms.py

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    weight = forms.DecimalField(validators=[validate_gtr])

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = [
            'name',
            'weight',
            'daily_food_min',
            'daily_food_max',          
            'species',
            'farmer',    
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].help_text = 'Name of Animal'
        self.fields['weight'].help_text = 'Weight in Kg'
        self.fields['species'].help_text = 'choose a species'
```

> validator.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _



def validate_gtr(value):
    if value > 100:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('(value) Kg. Animal is too heavy'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

---

> **Question**

As you can see i already wrote a simple validation `validate_gtr` to check the weight of my animals - it worked. 
Now i would like to validate `daily_food_min` and `daily_food_max` against each other, meaning that `daily_food_max` has to be greater then `daily_food_min`, when saving or when entering the numbers in my html form.

this was my approach

> forms.py

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    weight = forms.DecimalField(validators=[validate_gtr])
    daily_food_min = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, validators=[validate_food])
    daily_food_max = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, validators=[validate_food])
<...>
```

> validator.py

```
  <...>

def validate_food(daily_food_min, daily_food_max):
    if daily_food_min > daily_food_max:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('(daily_food_min) Kg. is higher then max.'),
            params={
                'daily_food_max': daily_food_max,
                'daily_food_min': daily_food_min,                  
                    },
        )
```

Unfortunately i receive i **Error Message** when i fill out my html form:

```
TypeError: validate_food() missing 1 required positional argument: 'daily_food_max'
```

how can i send both values to my validation or declare the positional argument ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). What you need is to validate the form (and all the fields) at once, rather than validate the fields individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright thanks to @Jordan M. hint in the docs, i figured out this soultion that worked form me.

i wrote a `clean()` Method and this is my updated form.

> forms.py

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    weight = forms.DecimalField(validators=[validate_gtr])
    daily_food_min = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    daily_food_max = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = [
            'name',
            'weight',
            'daily_food_min',
            'daily_food_max',          
            'species',
            'farmer',    
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].help_text = 'Name of Animal'
        self.fields['weight'].help_text = 'Weight in Kg'
        self.fields['species'].help_text = 'choose a species'

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
            daily_food_min = cleaned_data.get("daily_food_min")
            daily_food_max = cleaned_data.get("daily_food_max")

            if daily_food_min and daily_food_max:
                # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
                if daily_food_min > daily_food_max:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        "Food min. has to be less then Food max."
                    )
```